# Return feature.shape from server by using WCF and ArcGIS Silverlight API

Tags: wcf, silverlight, arcobjects, arcgis-server

I am using arcgis silverlight api

I all i need to do is to get geometry from feature by objectid to zoom to it

```
getFeature(objectid);
```

so i used WCF service to get the geometry but I found error that say

> Type 'System.__ComObject' cannot be serialized

can you help me please?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

Any reason you're not using an ArcGIS server service?
anyway you can't return arcobjects in a wcf service since it wouldn't know how to convert it into XML or json. You will  need to define a datacontract class with some simple properties that you convert between in each end. 
I also wrote the following blogpost way back when which might be helpful: http://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2010/03/11/sending-geometry-between-silverlight-and-the-server-using-wcf/ This uses the arcgis wpf and SL geometries for transferring since these have a data contract and share the same one.